# React dragged item going to original position after refresh

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface

i am using react-draggable package to make draggable cover image just like facebook.
when i drag the image and save it(internal api trigger). The page refreshes which leads to image going back to same position. Should i add dynamic position to img? If yes how to do it. Please guide me through or with any effective solution.

```
           <div style={{ height: "380px" }}>
                            <Draggable
                                    // bounds="parent"
                                bounds={{ bottom: 200 }}
                                axis="y"
                                >

                                    <img
                                        className={`m4e_m1n_c8e cover-pic-family 
                                         ${this.props.styleName}`}
                                        src={coverImage}
                                        alt="local"

                                    />
                                </Draggable>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Your code is not really showing anything - how do you save it's position? When that position is retrieved, how are you applying it to the image?

Comment: That is what i needed help on.